# Call performSelector NSObject instance without using self

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following code effectively schedules a delayed selector call and also effectively cancels all pending scheduled calls.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(triggerUpdateForNSIndexPath:)
           withObject:indexPath
           afterDelay:triggerIn];

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Also the following code schedules a selector for withObject and cancels that particular scheduled selector withObject.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(triggerUpdateForNSIndexPath:)
           withObject:indexPath
           afterDelay:triggerIn];

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(triggerUpdateForNSIndexPath:)
                                           object:indexPath];
```

My problem is that this is using `self` at the target and that means any other scheduled calls none related to my selector method `triggerUpdateForNSIndexPath` will be canceled by the `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];`. I have tried changing `self` to be an `NSObject` instance but the selector was never triggered.

How can I control scheduled selectors without having to know the exact `withObject`? To me creating an `NSObject` instance to replace using `self` seemed to make sense but I guess I'm off...

Essentially my worry is that in the future in my code I will call performSelector with a delay for a particular selector and the call `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];` will cancel it when it isn't related. This will introduce a ugly bug I want to avoid.

Comment: Use `NSTimer` which you can then `invalidate` if necessary?

Comment: Hey @trojanfoe you are actually right. I need to use a NSTimer. I will use that and keep scheduled NSTimers in an array so I can easily cancel all of the scheduled ones. I'm new to iOS so I didn't understand how some things worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:`, NSObject also has `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` method.

From [NSObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

`+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument`

Cancels perform requests previously registered with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

**Parameters**
*aTarget*
The target for requests previously registered with the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instance method

*aSelector*
The selector for requests previously registered with the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instance method.

*anArgument*
The argument for requests previously registered with the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instance method. Argument equality is determined using isEqual:, so the value need not be the same object that was passed originally. Pass nil to match a request for nil that was originally passed as the argument.

**Discussion**
All perform requests are canceled that have the same target as *aTarget*, argument as *anArgument*, and selector as *aSelector*. This method removes perform requests only in the current run loop, not all run loops.

Comment: Yes, I use those calls to cancel the specific scheduled selector withObject. But I want to on some cases simply cancel all scheduled selectors for the particular selector. I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to iOS so understanding this area was a bit difficult. What I ended up doing was to simply keep a map of the scheduled NSTimers. I could then cancel each individual one or all.